# what is the "editId" in Coq's XML Protocol document?

Tags: xml, coq, coq-tactic, coqide

In [Coq's XML Protocol document (for the Add operation)](https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/master/dev/doc/xml-protocol.md#command-add), a line reads `<int>${editId}</int>`. What is the editID here?

I asked this because I failed to interact with coqtop in the ideslave mode. Using `coq-8.6.1/theories/FSets/FSetCompat.v` as an example, I inputted

```
<call val="Init"><option val="none"/></call>
```

,

```
<call val="Add"><pair><pair><string>Require Import FSetInterface FSetFacts MSetInterface MSetFacts.</string><int>1</int></pair><pair><state_id val="1"/><bool val="true"/></pair></pair></call>
```

,

```
<call val="Add"><pair><pair><string>Set Implicit Arguments.</string><int>1</int></pair><pair><state_id val="2"/><bool val="true"/></pair></pair></call>
```

, and then

```
<call val="Add"><pair><pair><string>Unset Strict Implicit.</string><int>1</int></pair><pair><state_id val="3"/><bool val="true"/></pair></pair></call>
```

They all generated correct outputs. However, at this time when I typed

```
<call val="Add"><pair><pair><string>Module Backport_WSets
    (E:DecidableType.DecidableType)
    (M:MSetInterface.WSets with Definition E.t := E.t
                           with Definition E.eq := E.eq)
<: FSetInterface.WSfun E.</string><int>1</int></pair><pair><state_id val="4"/><bool val="true"/></pair></pair></call>
```

I got the following error:

```
[pid 48519] XML syntax error: Attribute value expected
[pid 48519] XML syntax error: Xml node expected
[pid 48519] XML syntax error: Xml node expected
[pid 48519] Unexpected XML message
[pid 48519] Expected XML node: call
[pid 48519] XML tree received: <int>1</int>
[pid 48519] XML syntax error: Xml node expected
[pid 48519] Unexpected XML message
[pid 48519] Expected XML node: call
[pid 48519] XML tree received: <pair>
  <state_id val="4"/>
  <bool val="true"/>
</pair>
[pid 48519] XML syntax error: Xml node expected
[pid 48519] XML syntax error: Xml node expected
```

I suspect that this error is because of the multi-line string, and maybe if I change editId, I should get the correct answer. Am I right? If no, what does editID do, and how should I deal with this error? Thanks for helping!

Comment: (Welcome to SO)(What is that funky character before `: FSetInterface.WSfun E.`?)

Comment: @greybeard Thanks! That's a less-than sign.

Comment: `a less-than sign` lo and behold! Shouldn't that be `&lt;`?

Comment: @greybeard Yeah you are right! The error was solved after I change `<` to `&lt;`! The error was not because of the line break but because of this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EditId` was removed in Coq 8.7; its original purpose and history is a bit complex due to intricacies of the protocol and historical issues.

Namely, the `Add` operation is synchronous in the sense that the user interface has to wait for a reply with the newly assigned identifier (`Stateid.t`) for the added span.

However, if a parser error occurred, the asynchronous feedback system needed a temporal identifier, `edit_id` served that purpose.

We removed `edit_id` as `Add` is synchronous anyway, so it makes sense for the caller of `Add` to use the synchronous error handler instead of the `edit_id`-based feedback.

Note that I **strongly** recommend against using the current synchronous version of `Add`. It forces the client to implement a complex blocking system, and it will be replaced soon by an asynchronous-friendly version [where the UI chooses the span_id upfront] . Such a version is already available in the ML API and exposed by SerAPI (*) and likely by the XML protocol itself starting in 8.8.

(*) The usual disclaimers apply: I am the author of SerAPI, also note that I was  the person behind the removal of `edit_id` from Coq 8.7.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The blocking is inconvenient indeed. I circumvented it by using a pty. I should try your SerAPI in the near future! Could you tell me why the error occurred when I feed in a multi-line string with "Add" (as shown in my question)?

Comment: You likely need to encode the line break using and html entity? It is instructive to see what CoqIDE `-debug` does.

Comment: Thanks! @greybeard just told me to change the `<` sign to `&lt;` and then the error was gone. So the error was not about line breaks. Thank you for your answer for edit_id!

Comment: Yup you need to encode quite a few things, see here the current quotings used in CoqIDE itself: https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/v8.7/ide/xml_printer.ml#L19

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to hurt to send an `editid` for an `Add`, even in 8.7, even if it's unused on the Coq side.

My XML-based fork of Proof General includes an `editid` for `Add` with 8.7, and no error occurs as a result.

Comment: I think the actual call was not changed to avoid bothering people, but the parameter is ignored.